# Error creating bean with Controller and entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, maven

I create a project with Spring and when I compile I got this errors with Controller and entityManagerFactory. This is my first project with Spring and I don`t know what is wrong. Could you help me?

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeesController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2996c83d' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2996c83d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/pszymanski/config/DBConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4921)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5231)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:405)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1595)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1184)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1380)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

pom.xml

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0

```
<groupId>pszymanski</groupId>
<artifactId>employees</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!---Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mysql Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Database Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:db.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.pszymanski.repository"})
public class DBConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driver.class.name")); //hibernate configuration for database
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.user.name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.pszymanski.model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        return factory.getObject();
    }
    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

EmployeeController:

```
 package com.pszymanski.controller;
import com.pszymanski.model.Employee;
import com.pszymanski.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class EmployeesController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeesPage(Model model) {

        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("employeesList", employeeList);

        return  "employees";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees-add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addEmployee(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("employees", new Employee());

        return"employees-add";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees-add/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEmployee( @ModelAttribute @Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result) {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "employees-add";
        }

        employeeRepository.save(employee);

        return"redirect:/employees";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees-add/cancel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String cancel() {

        return "redirect:/employees";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editEmployee(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){

        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "employee-add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/employees/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {

        employeeRepository.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/employees";
    }
}
```

EmployeeRepository:

```
 package com.pszymanski.repository;

import com.pszymanski.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long> {
}
```

Comment: What java, spring, maven versions are you using?

Comment: I`m using Java 1.8; Spring 4.3.7; Maven 4.0

Comment: I think you need to return a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean rather than an EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: But I return that [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory ...
return factory.getObject() ]

Comment: You might need an `@Transactional` annotation on your Repository, since you are using an EntityManagerFactory

Comment: @brt no, it dosn`t help :-/ 
I contemplate if any of the module versions "don`t bite" and may occur this errors

Comment: Did you create a Spring Bean Configuration file, specifying `<mvc: annotation-driven>` and which packages to scan to find beans?

Comment: Yes, I did create (in Java) -> @EnableWebMvc @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.pszymanski")

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa) for an example.  You are returning an EntityManagerFactory in your java config rather than the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.

```
   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.baeldung.persistence.model" });

      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

      return em;
   }
```

Just return the factory, not factory.getObject().